# Using real-world Kinect with Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to the ROS community.  I have a general question:   Is it possible to use a data from a real-world kinect to guide a simulated robot (e.g. PR2) in Gazebo?  If so, how hard will it be to do this?

My hope is that the interface will be a drop in change for a real robot (someday) and that I can test a gesture-based control algorithm against a simulated robot.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11164/using-real-world-kinect-with-gazebo/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there shouldn't be a problem with that; the real-world Kinect just publishes its data on a normal ROS topic, Gazebo publishes and subscribes also to normal topics, and your node can use both.

There is only one potential snag: gazebo uses [simulated time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock), while the Kinect will probably use wall time. You'll have to be careful about where and how you use timestamps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-12**:
Thanks Martin!